# How can I reinstall GRUB Bootloader on MBR after installing Kubuntu?

Tags: bootloader

I installed Ubuntu, but then installed Kubuntu over it (formated Ubuntu Partition) because Ubuntu is not compatible with almost any hardware on my PC. Problem is I'm stuck with an old GRUB that says Ubuntu in the options because in my attempts to make it compatible with my hardware I got an old Grub with an image with an Earth that says Debian.

How can I replace the GRUB with the one Kubuntu is supposed to install. I don't want to modify just the text, or the command to install on /sdaX, I want to actually re-write the MBR with the latest grub (reinstall the bootloader).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Kubuntu, it's easy.

From a command line, assuming a single disk drive, type

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` 
(this installs it in the mbr),

and then type `sudo update-grub`
(this updates the grub menu)

Comment: It sort of worked, but not fully. The Debian image is no longer there, however it says: GNU GRUB version 1.99-21Ubuntu3 and it still says Ubuntu on the menu and on the options. I can change the options text, but I cannot change what says on top. Is this the latest version?

Comment: This is the version that comes with whatever you were running when you installed it.  If you were running Kubuntu, then it installed the version that comes with Kubuntu; there would be no other version available at that time.  The menu should be whatever is standard for Kubuntu's grub menu, because it is a part of that distro, in in a file named /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  The menu should have choices for every available OS that it finds, with the standard Kubuntu choice at the top.  But I don't run KDE, so I'm not sure what it is supposed to say.  I may install it in a VM soon, and then I'll know.

Comment: @Agnes I run both Xubuntu and Lubuntu but GRUB always lists the kernels as just Ubuntu. I used grub-customizer to edit the names.