# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on MacBook Air (Mid 2012) [HELP]

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, macbook, 13.10

Yesterday I've decided to try Ubuntu 13.04 on my MacBook Air, within a day i really love and enjoy it!

So, I followed every step by step instructions on the Internet. Installation process run just fine...

In "something else" section I make:

- dev/sda1 efi
- dev/sda2 ext4 /
- dev/sda3 ext4 /home

After installation completed, I restart my Mac and nothing appear. Just white screen and folder with "question mark" on it.

I think I repeated my installation setup about 20 times, playing around with the "dev/sda" and the result still the same.

Right now my Mac doesn't have Operating System on it because I've deleted Mac OS X and doesn't have a backup files/system.

Can anyone help or guide me how am I supposed to do. Thanks in advance :(

[UPDATE]

Just want to update my post, currently running Ubuntu 13.10 without no errors! Thanks to this website and Google of course ;)

I am using MacBook Air (2012) so, I have to download the .iso specifically design for mac, here it is http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ and make sure to select "version+mac" iso version.

In the installations section, select "something else" and I did this

- dev/sda1 /boot 500mb
- dev/sda2 / 20000mb
- dev/sda3 swap area 4000mb
- dev/sda4 /home whatever left memory

Everything's work smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to install OS X on the computer in the future, do so now. OS X includes tools for managing boot loaders on a Mac that are more-or-less necessary for managing the boot process in EFI mode. Once you've re-installed OS X, you can install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or use `bless` to register GRUB as a valid boot loader.

If you want the computer to be a Linux-only system, I have two suggestions; try whichever sounds best to you:

- Download the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting) and write it to a USB flash drive. Try booting Linux using that. If it works, copy the entire contents of the USB flash drive to your `/dev/sda1` EFI System Partition (ESP) and see if you can boot without the flash drive. If this works, leave it that way.
- Use `gdisk` (in the `gdisk` package) to convert the partition table from GPT to MBR: Type `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`, then type `r` to enter the recovery & transformation menu, then type `g` to convert to MBR and answer the prompts. When you're done, reboot into an emergency system and [re-install GRUB.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139641/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-bootloader-on-mbr-after-installing-kubuntu) This process will convert the system to boot in BIOS mode rather than in EFI mode. A Linux-only install on a Mac is likely to be easier to manage in BIOS mode than in EFI mode.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain to me specifically about your 2 options above? Im not too professional though. Really need help, its been couple of days I tried to install.

Comment: My second option is explicit in what to do, albeit with a link to another question on this site that covers the GRUB re-installation process in more detail. If you need clarification of a specific point, please say what that point is.