# Help with grub comand screen now gone off

Tags: grubrescue, grub-legacy

I had just put the command in my grub to set root and the power went out whilst it was doing something and my monitor now says gnu grub 0.97.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing a bit more information. "whilst it was doing something" doesn't really help, nor does "now there is no screen" I can only assume that you mean either A) the screen left the room or B) nothing is displayed on your screen at boot.

Comment: Hi the PC went off an my monitor says no signal an lights are flashing on pc

Comment: What happens if you turn the system off and then back on? Do you get any output on the screen at all? If not it may be that your video card/circuitry was taken out by a power surge.

Comment: It's come back on to gnu grub 0.97 how can I get the system back up an running

Comment: grub 0.97? What version of Ubuntu are you running??? http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/grub.html

Comment: How would I find that out?

Comment: Google - GRUB 2 is the default boot loader and manager for Ubuntu since version 9.10 ... and Grub 1.99, packaged with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reinstall grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493612/how-to-reinstall-grub)

Comment: Is there no rescue command

Comment: I found some rescue commands here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem but in my case they failed miserably. The answer that worked for me is below.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of version I've been able to successfully recover from this problem (I managed to duplicate it today) using the Super Grub2 disk available [here.](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/)

By booting the live media and choosing Everything from the menu then choosing the newest kernel and booting into the previously unbootable system then reinstalling and updating grub.

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` To install grub2 to the MBR (changing sda if necessary to the drive you intend to boot from)

and then

`sudo update-grub` To update the menu

Finally insure the drive you intend to boot from is first in your BIOS boot order.

There was a Legacy Grub boot disk available, but it's outdated and no longer being developed.

Sources: Current experience, http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub-disk/ and [How can I reinstall GRUB Bootloader on MBR after installing Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139641/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-bootloader-on-mbr-after-installing-kubuntu/139642#139642)