# Grub problem on the boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have to write following code each time I start my PC.

```
set root=(hd0,8)
set prefix=(hd0,8)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Can anyone tell a littel what this commands do and what is Grub? Also, how to start pc without this?

Comment: When did the problem start?

Answer (score 0):

did you by change have another distro on your box that you've since deleted?

the commands you type in tell grub to use hd0 (first hdd read by bios) & 8th partition.   grub consists of many parts; part 1 is the MBR or first 512 byte sector of HDD that is really a pointer to next part. this pointer on your machine is likely pointing to an old /boot partition you've wiped/reused.   it can only point to one place and commonly is the last OS you installed.  when your system is running, the easiest fix is to have your system re-install grub on your hdd (or in the correct places)

[How can I reinstall GRUB Bootloader on MBR after installing Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139641/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-bootloader-on-mbr-after-installing-kubuntu)

to learn more about grub - I'd suggest the manual/doco firstly, but if web sites are more your thing try a search engine or

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html

IF you have only a single OS you can boot without grub; but its still useful if things go wrong, for example if an update or change (we make) causes kernel.panic on boot; we can tell grub to boot an older kernel, or change the params/options we made to get it to boot (eg. tell it to boot only in maintenance/recovery mode). grub is worth having unless you're sure you'll never have problems.